# Symfony 2.3: The "actions" extension is not enabled

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I am currently updating a Symfony 2.1 project to Symfony 2.3 (and later to 3.4).

I just got the error message `The "actions" extension is not enabled.`. Can someone tell me where I can find the fault? Google could not help me unfortunately....

thanks
Anton

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Symfony 2.1 to 2.2 upgrade guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.2.md):

> **FrameworkBundle**
>
> The `render` method of the `actions` templating helper signature and
>   arguments changed:
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $view['actions']->render('BlogBundle:Post:list', array('limit' => 2), array('alt' => 'BlogBundle:Post:error')) ?>
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $view['actions']->render($view['router']->generate('post_list', array('limit' => 2)), array('alt' => 'BlogBundle:Post:error')) ?>
> ```
>
> where `post_list` is the route name for the `BlogBundle:Post:list` controller, or if you don't want to create a route:
>
> ```
> <?php echo $view['actions']->render(new ControllerReference('BlogBundle:Post:list', array('limit' => 2)), array('alt' => 'BlogBundle:Post:error')) ?>
> ```

Does this lead you on the right track?